# Label is truncated in y-axis plotly

Tags: plotly

I have created a boxplot with boxply, everything looks good except the labels in y-axis are truncated. That's really frustrating because it's crucial information. When you go to `codepen.io/plotly/pen/gMPopL` and modify the name of trace2 you will see what's happing. I can't find how to modify the width of y-axis value in the documentation.

Comment: I did a quick fix that works for me. I added jquery and executed $('g[transform]').attr('transform', 'translate(120,100)');  in console.

Answer (score 1):

You can give more room for your axis labels by adjusting the margin.

in your layout variable add a new key "margin" of the form:

```
var layout = {
  title: 'Horizontal Box Plot',
  margin: {
    l: 200,
    r: 100,
    t: 50,
    b: 10
  }
};
```

l = left margin, r = right, t = top, b = bottom.  the values are in pixels.  You can include or exclude keys as you need.  In your case you likely want

```
margin: { l:100 }
```

where you can play with the number 100 to make the left margin as big as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is automargin option ready for this case. Example code:

```
var layout = {
    autosize: true,
    yaxis: {
      automargin: true
    }
  };
```

So your y label will show properly.

Comment: I feel like this should be the default of this property.